# How to run command on all mp4 files using txt file with multiple lines in batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, video, counting, nested-for-loop

So basically what I'm trying to do is have each line of a text file used as a key within mp4decrypt. So if I have 3 keys generated for Video.mp4 it should output Video_1.mp4, Video_2.mp4 and Video_3.mp4. Each having used 1 of the three keys within Keys.txt. And then have it do the same on all mp4 files within the directory.

The current code I have will run mp4decrypt on all mp4s but only use the very last key in the keys.txt file. And append _1 on the first file processed _2 on the second file processed and so on. But I need it to output files where Video.mp4 has three files with _1 to _3 then Video2.mp4 would have files with _1 to _3 and so on.

I tried using nested for loops but it didn't seem to work as it couldn't read the --key anymore.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "counter=1"

for /f "delims=" %%b in (keys.txt) do set key=%%b
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.mp4') do (
    mp4decrypt --key %key% --show-progress "%%a.mp4" "%%a_!Counter!.mp4"
    set /a counter+=1
    )
endlocal
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I just can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp4') do (
    set /a counter=0
    for /f "delims=" %%b in (keys.txt) do (
        set /a counter+=1
        mp4decrypt --key %%b --show-progress "%%a" "%%~na_!Counter!.mp4"
    )
)
```

should fix your problem [untested]

First, create a list of the existing `.mp4`s using `dir` - since you are creating new `.mp4`s, this prevents reprocessing the newly-created files.

The "delims=" applies the entire name-and-extension to `%%a`

For each such file found,
Initialise `counter` then for each line read from the `keys` file,

Bump the counter and execute the `mp4decrypt` using the key in `%%b` read from the `keys` file, the name-and-extension of the file in `%%a` and construct the new name from the name part only of %%a (`%%~na`) and the current value of `counter`.

Comment: You beat me too it by a half hour. But yours also looks much better than mine. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
set "counter=1"
for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ('type "keys.txt"') do (
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('mp4decrypt --key "%%b" --show-progress "%%i" "%%~ni_!Counter!.mp4"') do %%a
        set /a counter+=1
    )
)
endlocal`  Thank you for helping me out with this one.